# Laravel model, select query with hexadecimal

Tags: php, sql, laravel, db2-400

I'm having an issue returning a result from a query in laravel that is using CCSID for hexidecimal values. If I take the identifier in question and plug it into the query manually in my sql client it works:

```
SELECT          *
FROM            TableOne T1
WHERE           CAST(T1 . IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = x'0213725502A3BC45706AEE6001';
```

However, When I try this in my laravel model with the identifier as a param, it errors out and shows `x:identifier` instead of x and then the string:

```
$sql = "SELECT          *
    FROM            TableOne T1
    WHERE           CAST(T1 . IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = x':identifier'
";

    try {
        return DB::connection('odbc')->select($sql, [
            'identifier' => $identifier
        ]);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
```

How can I make this parameter inject correctly with the x so that it works as it does manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below query should help you. We can chain `table` and `whereRaw` in connection. You dont need to create raw query.

```
 return DB::connection('odbc')->table('TableOne')
                    ->whereRaw("CAST(IDENITIFIER AS CHAR(26) CCSID 65535) = x'?'",[$identifier])
                    ->get();
```

Comment: I tried this and also tried just using the '?' in my original query. I get an error that the hexadecimal constant is x'?' is not valid

Comment: The raw query works for me, but I don't know how to append the x and the parameter properly

Comment: @TomN. replace `->get();` with `->toSql();` see what raw query shown to you. I think it should match with the `$sql` you did.